# What it the real benefit from Erlang's fault tolerance for a web project?

Tags: erlang, lamp, fault-tolerance

Let's assume we have a web project in which we want to have ~10000 web clients connected to the server simultaneously. Let's also assume that one client session lasts about 25 minutes.

If we compare LAMP stack or any other popular web stack/framework (Ruby on Rails with Apache on Linux, etc.) to a web project built in Erlang/OTP - **what does Erlang/OTP have in terms of fault tolerance that other frameworks don't?**

What event can happen to a client that will cause the whole LAMP stack crash, while Erlang/OTP will stand its ground?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that a typical LAMP-stack does employ some fault tolerance. In particular, if a request in the LAMP stack fail, only that request will, while the rest of the code will run on. This kind of protection allows you to have faults in a single request without that hurting other requests.

Erlang provides this idea of "able to cope with smaller unforseen errors" at a much finer grained scale. You may have other subsystems in an application, and the same kind of tolerance to errors can be extended to those. You won't get it "for free", but the tooling is there to build a system which is robust. Imagine a client error in the LAMP stack. This will often lead to a disconnect of that client. It may not be so in Erlang and the client can keep on running.

For a system of 10000 clients, Erlang provides the advantage that you can have a process per client. Or perhaps 10 processes per client. That is much harder to pull of in many languages since a process/thread is rather heavy and expensive. Note that interprocess communication between the clients are easy, also if some clients are on another machine (imagine extending to a distributed cluster some day).

If you write your code in a certain way, you can make sure that if a client crashes, for one reason or the other, then its state is properly cleaned up by other processes. That can avoid lots and lots of small nasty leaks in state as well.

Comment: Found this recently on HN: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-February/064277.html

Answer (score 4):

**what does Erlang/OTP have in terms of fault tolerance that other frameworks don't?**

Now, Erlang/OTP has very minimal if not, Zero side effects. Because of its concurrency, a web server like **[`yaws`](http://yaws.hyber.org)** literally spawns a small web server for every connection. If one user is affected by a given web service fault in your application, all other users will never notice and the only that users process may exit.

With OTP, you can build applications with a number of **[`supervisors`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html)**, such that if a server goes down, its restarted and many other functions and options you may need.

Erlang's distribution allows us to write distributed applications. I have personally used `yaws web server` in building a web application.

My experience is that which ever web server you may pick, say **`Mochiweb`**, a tutorial found here: **http://alexmarandon.com/articles/mochiweb_tutorial/**, is quite impressive in performance. Infact, a few years back, the oldest version of yaws web Server was bench marked with the (then) newest version of `Apache`, and the **[results of the bench mark are very awakening](http://www.sics.se/~joe/apachevsyaws.html)**. When i went through a **[million user comet application with Mochiweb](http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-1)**, which has **[Part 2](http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-2)** and **[Part 3](http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-3)**, i was impressed. These are some of the few examples of powerful web frameworks built for the web.

And by the way, have you heard of these new `NO SQL Databases` with `REST (HTTP) interface` developed in Erlang/OTP e.g. **[Membase Server](http://www.couchbase.com/sites/default/files/uploads/all/whitepapers/Membase-Technical-Whitepaper.pdf)** [home page here: **http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/membase-server**], **[Couch DB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)**, and **[Riak](http://basho.com/)**, their performance is very impressive, meaning that their web/REST interface is very stable and due to their impressive , documented write through put, they have proved that their underlying Technology (Erlang/OTP), was built not only for high availability and fault-tolerant systems only, but for the web too! Just read through this document: **http://blog.couchbase.com/why-membase-uses-erlang**

Many more web frameworks built in erlang and are very impressive can be found listed on the wiki page here: **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)**. A probably better summary of its features that make it powerful on the web can be found in here: **http://cs.nyu.edu/~lerner/spring10/projects/Erlang.pdf**